# JQuery validation for string value

Tags: jquery, validation

how do I check if a field has a string value tht contains letters 'abc' containing in it using Jquery ??

I need to check a field that contains a string value, if the field contains the characters 'abc' I need to disable few fields. Please let me know how I can validate in jquery??

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#myInput").val() == "abc") {
   $("#myOtherInput").attr("disabled","disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is like:

```
$('#text_id').keyup(function(){
   if (this.value === 'abc'){
       // disable other fields
   }
});
```

**Or with vanilla javascript:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('text_id');
el.onkeyup = function(){
   if (this.value === 'abc'){
       // disable other fields
   }
};
```

Where `text_id` is supposed to be the `id` of the element you want to check for.

Answer (score 0):

YOu dont need JQuery.
do something like this

```
var s = "foo";
alert(s.indexOf("oo") != -1);
```

it'll tell you if the variable s contains the text "oo" or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(":input[value*='abc']").length > 0) {
    // Disable fields
}
```

This will find you any input field that contains (written somewhere in the field value) abc, though obviously replace ":input" with whatever applies in your case.

Comment: instead of :input, should I be replcing it with #FieldName or :FieldName?

Comment: #FieldName means you have an input with id="FieldName".  :input is a special selector in jquery which selects all inputs and some non-inputs like textarea.  So :FieldName wouldn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputString = $('#inputfield').val(); //get value from field
if ((inputString.indexOf("abc") != -1) == true) {
   //disable fields here...
}
```

^_^